# How should I parse a Facebook Oauth token's expire date to store in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, postgresql, oauth

I'm using OAuth to authenticate my app to access a user's facebook details using OAuth.  Recently, I migrated the database to use PostgreSQL, and now am having trouble storing the token information when returned from Facebook.

The exact error is:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1350424800"
: INSERT INTO "authentications" ("created_at", "oauth_expires_at", "oauth_token", "provider", "uid", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
```

Strangely, this wasn't the case with SQLite, so it's clearly something to do with the format in which Facebook returns the expiry date ("1350424800").  Any thoughts on how I should parse this to make it work?

I'm not doing anything clever with the way it's created at present, simply:

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create(uid: auth['uid'], provider: auth['provider'], oauth_token: auth['credentials'].token, oauth_expires_at: auth['credentials'].expires_at)
end
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Raghu: please don't link to the manual of an unsupported versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1350424800"

You have a nummeric Unix Timestamp value here – whereas the PostgreSQL data type `timestamp` obviously has to be given in another format.

And looking here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE, you can see some of the accepted formats, but a nummeric Unix Timestamp does not appear to be listed there.

So you’ll have to convert/format the value into one of the accepted formats first; there might be a function designed to do this in PostgreSQL … (if not, Google should help).

Comment: Brilliant - thanks, and for those using Ruby, it's simply Time.at(1350424800) to convert into a PostgreSQL format.

Comment: @idrysdale: or you could simply use PostgreSQL's built in function: `to_timestamp(1350424800)`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/518

Comment: If he is using sqlite in development it wouldn't be a good idea to use postgres specific methods. And even if he isn't, it would still be better to solve the problem using ruby than something database specific. Databases can change and this certainly won't effect performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem is the variable type in postgres. If you have 'oauth_expires_at' as a 'datetime' you should convert the string timestamp to a date time. In Rails you can easily convert it with Time.at like this:

> ... oauth_expires_at: Time.at(auth['credentials'].expires_at)

rewrite your function as follows:

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create(uid: auth['uid'], provider: auth['provider'], oauth_token: auth['credentials'].token, oauth_expires_at: Time.at(auth['credentials'].expires_at))
end
```

If you want even more flexibility and use it also with omniauth-twitter you do something like this. I'm using the rail's try method to gracefully handle the cases when there is no expires_at in twitter or other social media

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authentications, dependent: :destroy

    def create_authentication(oauth)
        authentications.create!(
            provider: oauth['provider'], 
            uid: oauth['uid'], 
            oauth_token: oauth['credentials']['token'],
            oauth_secret: oauth['credentials'].try(:[],'secret'),
            oauth_token_expires_at: oauth['credentials'].try(:[],'expires_at') ? Time.at(oauth['credentials'].try(:[],'expires_at')) : nil,
            data: oauth.to_json.to_s
        )
    end 
end
```